# Complicated convergence of nonlinear term

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $1<p<\infty$, $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ be open, bounded with $\partial\Omega\in C^1$. Assume that $u_k\to u$ weakly in $W^{1,p}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^n)$. We know that $u_k\to u$ strongly in $W^{1,q}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $q$ such that $1<q<p<\infty$. Lets denote $u=(u^1,\ldots,u^n)$.

I want to prove the following convergence
$$ \int_\Omega |\nabla u_k|^{p-2}\nabla u_k^i u_k^j \cdot \nabla v \, dx \to \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^{p-2}\nabla u^i u^j \cdot \nabla v \, dx $$
for all $v\in C_0^\infty(\Omega;\mathbb{R})$ and all $i,j=1,\ldots,n.$

It is supposed to be an easy task, but I struggle with it for some time. I have tried adding and substracting things under integral, but it becomes even messier to work with...

Comment: Could you provide a reference for the claim that $W^{1,p}$ embedds compactly in $W^{1,q}$? Or is this part of the assumptions? Also some motivation/background/reference for the question would be nice.

Comment: I am terribly sorry, there should be $p-2$ in the exponents. I was working with $p$-power gradient earlier and got these two things mixed up... Now it is corrected. This improved convergence is a consequence of the theorem (without number) in this paper: http://hilltop.bradley.edu/~mou/hlm.pdf

Comment: The reason I am trying to get convergence in that form is due to information given on page 6 in http://hilltop.bradley.edu/~mou/hlm.pdf. It looks much better than passing to to limit with $\int |\nabla u_k|^p u_k \cdot v\, dx$.

Comment: Why does $|\nabla u_k|^{p-2}\nabla u_k^i u_k^j \cdot \nabla v\in L^1$?

Comment: @Tomás, is this supposed to be a hint?

Comment: No @Kamil. I fail to see why does that functions belong to $L^1$. Do you know why?

Comment: $\int ||\nabla u_k|^{p-2}\nabla u_k^i u_k^j \cdot \nabla v|\leq C \int |\nabla u_k|^{p-1} |u_k| \leq C\lVert \nabla u_k\rVert_{p}^{p-1}\lVert u_k\rVert_{p}$ which is finite due to boundedness of appropriate sequences.